# why readyState is NOT equal to 4?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, debugging, readystate

I have tried to learn how to receive data from database using ajax, and i have some problem...

the problem is when I submit the query I dont see any thing...
i know that the problem is because the readyState is NOT equal to 4...but why?

I have this code on the index.html file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
    var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
    var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>



<form name='myForm'>
   Max Age: <input type='text' id='age' /> <br />
   Max WPM: <input type='text' id='wpm' />
   <br />
   Sex: <select id='sex'>
          <option>m</option>
          <option>f</option>
        </select>

    <input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL' />
</form>
```

and this code on the ajax-example.php file:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "*************";
$dbname = "*************";
    //Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    // Retrieve data from Query String
$age = $_GET['age'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];
$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];
    // Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($sex);
$wpm = mysql_real_escape_string($wpm);
    //build query
$query = "SELECT * FROM ajax_example WHERE ae_sex = '$sex'";
if(is_numeric($age))
    $query .= " AND ae_age <= $age";
if(is_numeric($wpm))
    $query .= " AND ae_wpm <= $wpm";
    //Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    //Build Result String
$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Name</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Age</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Sex</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>WPM</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_name]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_age]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_sex]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_wpm]</td>";
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

}
echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$display_string .= "</table>";
echo $display_string;
?>
```

Comment: Does it show the headers? Because there's also a problem with `$display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_name]</td>";`. It should be: `"<td>".$row["ae_name"]."</td>";`.

Answer (score 1):

The order of operations must be:

1. Create AJAX object
2. Open a connection
3. Set readystatechange handler
4. Send request.

You have items 2 and 3 in the wrong order, so the event handler is being cleared and is never called.

EDIT: It should also be noted that `new XMLHttpRequest` has been fully cross-browser since 2007, with the release of IE7. You don't need to use those ActiveXObjects now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of two things:

- `localhost` is being used as the domain; it should be `127.0.0.1`
- `ajax-example.php` is running on localhost, but the associated HTML file is not

Answer (score 0):

var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;

> you should use double and(&&)
>   try it

var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&&wpm=" + wpm + "&&sex=" + sex;